# My power strip has (what appears to be) a burn mark. What do I do?

Tags: electrical, extension-cord, power

I got an power strip from IKEA around 12 months back.  I used it for at my desk with the laptop, pc, printer and light plugged in simultaneously. Now I discovered when I was moving that there's a burn mark midway covering around a sixth of the circumference and around 0.5 cm long. There's clearly heating since it's deformed/bent but it's hard to judge the extent of the damage.

- Since it's only a year old, is it reasonable to go back to IKEA and ask for a replacement?
- Could the fact that I used the extension cord on a non-earthed wall socket have contributed to the problem (old dutch houses just don't come with them...) and if so, I am liable to see this problem again?
- Is it safe to continue using this one?

[pic http://www.ikea.com/nl/nl/images/products/koppla-contactdoos-schakelaar--contact__0293166_PE425719_S4.JPG](http://www.ikea.com/nl/nl/images/products/koppla-contactdoos-schakelaar--contact__0293166_PE425719_S4.JPG)

Comment: I've had something like this happen with a mouse USB cord due to external heating (it was a portion that was near the vent output of the PC) - Was it an actual burn mark (with scorching/melting), or was the insulation just discolored and brittle?

Comment: I had 3 larger size power strips from Ikea, none of them had a burn mark, but every now and them, when plugging something it, there'd be a hiss or pop ... I was lazy and never tossed them - even though I completely agree with @diceless comment below. Luckily in the 10 years this was occurring nothing happened. Upon a recent move, I tossed them and am super thankful that I finally got those pieces of crap out of my life. Not sure I really trust such items to an Ikea branding product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't risk your life over a power strip.  Throw it away and get a new one.

You can try taking it back and Ikea is pretty good with customer service.  But I personally wouldn't be trusting an Ikea power strip with my computer equipment.  I would get something a little more heavy duty and has surge protection.

Also is your printer laser or ink jet?  If laser you should be treating that device as a small appliance.  IE, no power strip/extension cords as they tend to draw high current during the printing processes.